# Enable user interaction with UINavigationBar subviews that extend past the bounds of the bar

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uinavigationbar, addsubview, subviews

I have custom views and buttons that I have added as subviews of my UINavigationBar. Their frames are set such that they begin halfway down the nav bar and extend past the normal bounds of the nav bar. I also have another subview that from time to time must be displayed as a modal looking view, but on the iPhone. To achieve this I have set his frame to 0,0,320,480 and added him as a subview of the nav bar. Everything LOOKS ok, but user interaction is disabled on the section of the view that is displayed below the nav bar, (i.e. 0,44,320,456).

Similar situations arise with my other objects. How can I enable user interaction with these views? Is there a way to do this in the opposite manner such as having a view begin in the nav controller's view and extend upward to cover the nav bar? (i.e. 0,-44,320,480) ?

Seems like a simple task but I have tried everything I can think of, including toggling showing / hiding the nav bar with / without animation to make it get out of the way, but there is a button that I need to show only as part of the navigation bar and it needs to sit on top of an actual uinavigationbar.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
~Arash